# Matching "Wibble A, B, C2, D" using PERL-regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

> ... Foo, Bar, **Wibble A, B, C2, N, J,** Baz, Qux, More, More, ...
>
> ... Bar, Qux, **Wibble D, E, J, N6, O,** Foo, Foo, More, More, ... and so on

How do I match highlighted part of these strings using PERL-compatible regular expressions?

It starts with a word "Wibble" and continues with one or two character components separated by a comma until next word.

Comment: You're going to need to clarify exactly what defines the part of the string you want to match.

Comment: a comma is a character, too. you might want 'uppercase word character, or digit'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, this may work for you:

```
/Wibble( [A-Z]\d?,)*/
```

Comment: this does not actually capture anything other than the last `( [A-Z]\d?,)*` matched, which is generally useless. (it's something like ` J,`

Comment: @sreservoir for the purpose of replacing, this one is pretty fine. Thanks for the tip, Amber!

Answer (score 1):

`/Wibble((?:\s+[A-Z0-9]{1,2},)*)/`

check `$1`.

of course, when you say uppercase and then have numbers in your example, some exceptions have to be made.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
/(Wibble(?:\s[A-Z0-9]{1,2},)+)/
```

Comment: this, too, does not actually capture what he seems to want.

Answer (score 0):

not-at-all-serious answer: `/(Wibble A, B, C2, N, J,)/`

Comment: There could anything after "Wibble", but no longer than two characters and in upper case.